# how to run CGI script with parameters from console

Tags: c, cgi

I've wrote CGI script for www.

This script expects two parameters through GET method, multiply these numbers and write result into the file.

```
mult.cgi?m=1&n=2
```

But now I want to use this script from console too.
I'tried something like

```
./mult.cgi?m=1&n=2
```

But it didnt work, how can I send parameters to script?

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
QUERY_STRING="m=2&n=4" ./mult.cgi
```

Comment: No, that syntax sets the variable just for the child process.

Answer (score 0):

It acts out like a perl script. (correct me if I'm wrong here)

So if you want to run it via the console:

`perl mult.cgi 1 2`

as for the parameters, you need to convert it to: `$ARGV[1]` and `$ARGV[2]`..

**NOTE** `$ARGV[0]` is the cgi script (filename) in this case.

Also, you might be required to put: `#!/usr/bin/perl` at the very top of the cgi script.

Comment: Its script written in C language.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Well atleast you should've tagged `c` in your question, or mentioned it. Sorry but only CGI/Perl scripts can be run from the console (correct me if i'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
telnet hostname 80
GET /path/to/script/mult.cgi?m=1&n=2
```

Which emulates a port 80 (www) connection to the server and executes the script with given parameters.